# jquery ui combobox dropdown alignment off when extended

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm using this version of combobox... [combobox](http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/03/finishing-jquery-ui-autocomplete_4743.html)

but having a few problems which you can see in the following screenshots...

[image: closed dropdown]

[image: opened dropdown]

First the dropdown arrow dissapears.

Second when the dropdown is opened everything gets 'extended' to the length of the dropdown.

Third when a selection is made there's an 'X' that should appear in the input box but it doesn't.

Here's the css associated with the combobox, if there's any other code you'd like me to add please ask.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>                      
    <legend>test</legend>
    <table>
    <col width="33%">
    <tr>
        <td class="rightcol">
            <label>select:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>a</option>
                <option>b</option>
                <option>c</option>
                <option>d</option>
                <option>e</option>
           </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.combobox-class{
 width: 110px; /* combobox width */
}

.ui-combobox{
 padding-left: 1px; /* padding for input field */
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-right: 1.8em;
 position: relative;
}

.ui-combobox-input{
 padding-left: 4px;
 margin: 0px;
 background: white;
}

.ui-combobox-button{
 position: absolute;
 width: 1.8em !important;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-left: -1px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}

.ui-combobox-button .ui-button-text{
 padding: 0em;
}

.ui-combobox .ui-autocomplete{
 max-height: 10em;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, total mess up on my part... had commented out this line of code from the jquery-ui.css file for some reason and for got about it...

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
}
```